Permission denied trying to install Anaconda on Chromebook (linux)?
I am trying to install Anaconda on my Chromebook.
But in the middle, I hit a permission issue:
[/home/chronos/user/anaconda3] >>>>
PREFIX=/home/chronos/user/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Anaconda3-2024.06.1-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 438: /home/chronos/user/anaconda3/_conda: Permission denied

I tried to run grant _conda permission by running
chmod o_rx _conda 

Then when I do ls -l:
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 chronos chronos 34511368 Jul 30 14:22 _conda 
-drwxr-xr-x. 2 chronos chronos 4096 Jul 30 14:18 install_tmp

But when I retry the download I hit the same permissioning issue.

Are you installing it on Chronos and not Crostini?
